# How to move UPLOADS folder in sub-domain which hosted in another server

Tags: uploads, ftp

I want to move the uploads folder to a sub-domain. it hosted on another server.
there are a lot of guides which is mentioned move the folder to a subdomain which hosted on the same as the main site is. like [this](http://www.dezzain.com/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-uploads-path-to-subdomain/comment-page-6/#comment-151639)

Now, what about a sub-domain on the other server? how can I set FTP's user and password in WordPress?

ps: I found out [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-to-ftp/) plugin. but is there any way to set it without any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Warning! Nothing of the proposed below was tested.

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'update_attachment_url');
function update_attachment_url($data)
{
    $data['url'] = str_replace('http://main-domain/', 'http://sub-domain.com', $data['url']);
    $data['baseurl'] = str_replace('http://main-domain/', 'http://sub-domain.com', $data['baseurl']);

    return $data;
}
```

[Code source](https://www.webnots.com/move-wordpress-images-folder-to-subdomain/).

Also you can try to change the values of `upload_path` and `upload_url_path` found in the `wp_options` MySQL table.

Remember to run [Search Replace DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) to change all published image paths.

Comment: as I said my problem is all guide just is about a subdomain in the same server.  my subdomain is on another server. in your guide how can I set ftp user and pass?